# Ionic/Angular async data from storage

Tags: angular, promise, ionic4

I have this code in a Ionic/Angular app that I use to get user data from storage (@ionic/storage):

```
constructor(public storage: Storage) {
   console.log('constructor START')
   this.getFromStorage();
   console.log('constructor END')
}

async getFromStorage() {
   console.log('getFromStorage 1')
   this._user = await this.storage.get(this.USER_KEY);
   console.log('getFromStorage 2')
}
```

I would like to use async/await to get data from storage in synchronous mode (without then/catch functions), but I have the following logs:

```
constructor START
getFromStorage 1
constructor END
getFromStorage 2
```

I would get it instead:

```
constructor START
getFromStorage 1
getFromStorage 2
constructor END
```

Comment: You cannot convert async data to be synchronous. You should use the `then/catch` signature to ensure the flow.

Comment: It's hard not to write an essay as preamble to an answer to this question. In a nutshell, 
(1) If a function is asynchronous (it returns Promise), then its caller(s) are also asynchronous (it should also return Promise).
(2) As a consequence of (1) an object/class constructor (if that's what your `constructor()` is) shouldn't be asynchronous - it must return an Instance, not a Promise.
(3) As a consequence of (2) a constructor can do as much synchronous stuff as they like but shouldn't do anything asynchronous.
Doesn't answer the question but explains why it probably shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @enfix How did you solve it?